# Promising whilst looping through with mongoose queries - Node Bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bluebird

I would like to do a query inside of each loop within a map and then once finished the loops and queries do something else:

```
Promise.map(results, function (item, index) {
         return Clubs.findAsync({name: name})
        .then(function (err, info) {
            if (err) {console.info(err); return err};
            console.info(info);
            return info;
        })
        .done(function (info) {
            return info;
        });
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.info('done');
        req.flash('success', 'Results Updated');
       res.redirect('/admin/games/'+selectedLeague);
    });
```

In this, `done` will console before the `info` is consoled. Meaning I can't do anything with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [bluebird.done](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#donefunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----void):

> .done([Function fulfilledHandler] [, Function rejectedHandler ]) ->
>   void
>
> Like .then(), but any unhandled rejection that ends up here will be
>   thrown as an error. Note that generally Bluebird is smart enough to
>   figure out unhandled rejections on its own so .done is rarely
>   required. As explained in the error management section, using .done is
>   more of a coding style choice with Bluebird, and is used to explicitly
>   mark the end of a promise chain.

So in your `Promise.map`, it just get an array of `undefined` or somthing else, but not `Promise`, so the map is resolved after it gets the map. Use `.then` to return a `Promise`.

```
Promise.map(results, function (item, index) {
     return Clubs.findAsync({name: name})
    .then(function (err, info) {
        if (err) {console.info(err); return err};
        console.info(info);
        return info;
    })
    // vvvv use `.then` here, not `.done`, done returns nothing, not promise.
    .then(function (info) {
        return info;
    });
}).done(function (data) {
    console.info('done');
    req.flash('success', 'Results Updated');
   res.redirect('/admin/games/'+selectedLeague);
});
```

Comment: Mind blown a little bit. `.done` is just to show myself that I'm done here :) I thought it was promise 101. Nice one :)